# ringtone picker is not working

Tags: android, android-preferences

i'm using this lib [android.v4.preference.fragment](https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment), having issue with ringtone preference, the below code works superb for ICS and below version phones, but it launches duplicate ringtone dialog for ICS and above phones, i.e it launches 2 ringtone preference dialogs.

ringtonepref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    {
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String path = settings.getString("prefnotificationTone", "content://settings/system/notification_sound");                   

        Uri uri = !TextUtils.isEmpty(path) ? Uri.parse(path) : null;

        Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);

        //intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALL);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, uri);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, true);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);

        getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);
    }

    return true;
}
```

i'm handling like this in activity result

```
case 1000:
         if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
         {
             Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
             SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
             Editor editor = settings.edit();
             editor.putString("prefnotificationTone", uri == null ? "": uri.toString());
             editor.commit();   
         }
         else
             {

             }
         break;
```

i tried another way to compare the devices i.e ICS and above launch the default one else allow custom intent, but for Jelly bean and other devices i'm not getting the event to `OnPreferenceChangeListener`, now i'm confused any help.

Thanks

Comment: You might find [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/RingtonePreference.html) and [this](https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment/issues/1) links helpful. 

By the way, since the PreferenceFragment is not supported in the support library, 
I'm using a different approach, which launches a PreferenceActivity for API Level < 11, 
and PreferenceFragment for API Level 11+.

Comment: Hi, thats good idea, but i have a fragment i.e a viewpager. How can i launch activity in viewpager it can't be possible right?, can you provide me a sample code if you dont mind please.

Comment: Hi @DerGolem, any help i'm waiting. I'm using viewfragment. So we cant use activity inside it right?. thanks in advance

Comment: `we cant use activity inside it` Not an Activity inside a Fragment. But a Fragment inside an Activity. You can still open Activites from both Fragments and Activities.

Comment: Hi, i'm still confused i'm using android.v4.fragment i.e support library, if i launch activity for older version and for new version i have to use preferencefragment its of type android.fragment, in this case again it wont work. overall it will be mess. Any help pls. thanks

Comment: @DerGolem, i solved my problem.. thanks lot dear, thank u for your kind help & sorry if i have troubled u toooo much.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a workflow bug on the library and there are more than workaround for it that you can find [here](https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment/issues/1).

Comment: Yes, i simply created a preference object i.e like this `<Preference 
             android:title="@string/RING_TONE_SETTING" 
             android:summary="@string/RING_TONE_SETTING_DESCRIPTION" 
             android:ringtoneType="notification"
             android:persistent="true"
             android:showDefault="false"
             android:key="prefnotificationTone"/>`

It worked at last, thanks

Comment: I need one more help, by default call tone is coming as default tone and its visible at top, how to make sms tone as default tone and show it at top?

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't help with that.