# Is there a way to convert fragment to android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

my app requires to use both android.support.v4.app.Fragment and default fragment which has support from API 11 onwards, can anyone tell me how to cast the default API 11 Fragment to android.support.v4.app.Fragment?.

Is it possible?, in my app i need to use settingsfragment, this does not support android.support.v4.app.Fragment. Any help

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is possible, unless you maintain two code bases for different targets.

Comment: How to overcome this situation.. any idea?

Comment: For the settings, I use an Activity. It checks the OS version. If < 11, it launches a PreferenceActivity. Else, it launches a PreferenceFragment. Very easy. It's a workaround to the problem of not having the PreferenceFragment included into the support library. If you can wait 3 or 4 hours, I can answer post the code I'm using to do the trick (I'm kinda busy at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do a cast as you want.
Try to do that:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
{
    // user fragment
}
else
{
    // user android.support.v4.app.Fragment
}
```

Comment: But actually i have viewpager adapter, so it does return a generic fragment i,e 
How to overcome this scenario?..

`@Override
 public Fragment getItem(int index) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   switch (index) {
         case 0:
                case 1:
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
{
    // user fragment
}
else
{
    // user android.support.v4.app.Fragment
}`

Comment: yes, you should implement two adapter. One for support fragment and another for new android fragment (> 11). You should manage both.

Answer (score 0):

Can anyone tell me how to cast the default API 11 Fragment to android.support.v4.app.Fragment?

> This is not possible because android.support.v4.app.Fragment is completely different class than the framework's fragment class and even when android.support.v4.app.Fragment run on Android 3.0 or above, its implementation is still used; it does not try to switch to the framework's implementation.

Is it possible?, In my app I need to use settingsfragment, this does not support android.support.v4.app.Fragment?

> You can't use the current implementation of framework's [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html), but you can use [this library](https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment) that maintains compatibility layer for Android 1.6 and up and it's PrefrenceFragment inherits from android.support.v4.app.Fragment not the framework's one.

Comment: HI, i used this library but causing issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27970723/ringtone-picker-is-not-working

Comment: I posted an answer there. It's a known issue in the library.